# StoreKit SKStoreProductViewController in React Native

Tags: swift, objective-c, react-native, storekit

I'm looking to add StoreKit's [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller) into a React Native project (without using a third-party library). Would like the Store view to show up as a modal when the user taps a "get app" button, which will pass the iTunesID of the product to be displayed.

While RN's documentation explains how to [integrate a native view component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-ios) into a project, I'm not sure I'm understanding how this would translate to a view controller.

While I prefer a solution in objective-c, I can accept a solution that uses Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to parse what I needed from https://github.com/rh389/react-native-store-view. Though I had tried installing the package, it had some breaking issues - but I extracted the key elements and documented them in this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/raffibag/213de82365166e647af975e85076e2ff

In a nutshell:

1. Pull in native libraries and StoreKit component in new header and Obj-C files in your root app directory (`RCTStoreViewManager.m` and `RCTStoreViewManager.h`);
2. Create a bridge file to connect js methods with the Obj-C / native methods (`index.ts`);
3. Pull the js methods into your RN component (`Component.js`)